# Embedded Jetty Closing Open Connections During Graceful Termination

Tags: java, curl, jersey, jetty, embedded-jetty

I have written a basic embedded jetty server (with jersey to define endpoints), and need it to terminate gracefully (in response to a SIGINT). I would like all in-flight requests to finish processing and return results to the requestor (up until some timeout), while not accepting any new connections/requests.

The current behavior that I'm seeing is that in-flight requests are completed correctly, but the connections to clients are terminated (so they don't receive the responses to their requests).

When creating my `Server` instance, I set `setStopAtShutdown` to `true` and set a value for `setStopTimeout`. I also configure the `StatisticsHandler`. From what I can tell from the docs, this is what's required to enable graceful termination.

Here is my jetty server set up:

```java
// For additional Jetty configuration options see:
// https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/embedding-jetty.html#_like_jetty_xml
public static Server createServer(
    int port, int shutdownGracePeriodMillis, int httpServerThreads, int httpIdleTimeoutMillis) {
    // Create server
    QueuedThreadPool threadPool = new QueuedThreadPool();
    threadPool.setMaxThreads(httpServerThreads);
    Server server = new Server(threadPool);
    HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
    ServerConnector http = new ServerConnector(server, new HttpConnectionFactory(config));
    http.setPort(port);
    http.setIdleTimeout(httpIdleTimeoutMillis);
    server.addConnector(http);

    // Enable StatisticsHandler (required for graceful termination)
    StatisticsHandler stats = new StatisticsHandler();
    stats.setHandler(server.getHandler());
    server.setHandler(stats);
    ServerConnectionStatistics.addToAllConnectors(server);

    // Configure graceful termination
    server.setStopAtShutdown(true);
    server.setStopTimeout(shutdownGracePeriodMillis);

    // Associate Jersey with Jetty
    JettyHttpContainer container =
        ContainerFactory.createContainer(JettyHttpContainer.class, new AppResourceConfig());
    server.setHandler(container);

    return server;
}
```

Here is my jersey resource. It uses `Thread.sleep` to simulate some long-running request that needs to complete before the server shuts down.

```java
@POST
@Consumes("application/json")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String testEndpoint() {
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        try {
            logger.info("Number: " + i);
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (Exception e) { }
    }

    logger.info("Request completed!");

    return "Hello, world!\n";
}
```

I run the server and issue the following curl command

```sh
curl -v --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
  --request POST \
  --data '' \
  http://localhost:4200/testEndpoint
```

When I send a SIGINT to the server process while this request is still waiting for a response I see on the server:

```
INFO  c.a.a.s.resources.Resource - Number: 0
INFO  c.a.a.s.resources.Resource - Number: 1
^C {{NOTE: SIGINT issued here}}
[Thread-1] INFO  o.e.jetty.server.AbstractConnector - Stopped ServerConnector@32c726ee{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:4200}
INFO  c.a.a.s.resources.AuctionResource - Number: 2
INFO  c.a.a.s.resources.AuctionResource - Number: 3
INFO  c.a.a.s.resources.AuctionResource - Request completed!
```

We can see from the server logs that the request is completed correctly. The curl command never gets its response of "Hello, world!" though (which it does in a regular not interrupted request).

The curl output looks like this:

```
*   Trying ::1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 4200 (#0)
> POST /testEndpoint HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:4200
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: application/json
> Content-Length: 0
> 
* Empty reply from server
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

I expected that I should get the correct reply from the service, but instead get an empty reply from the server. What further config is required to not close the connections of in-flight requests during graceful termination for an embedded jetty server?

Comment: What version of Jetty?